# Could "only Russia’s senior-most officials have authorized" the efforts to leak sensitive emails related to the 2016 U.S. presidential election?

Tags: united-states, russia, hacking

There was a [joint statement](https://www.dni.gov/index.php/newsroom/press-releases/215-press-releases-2016/1423-joint-dhs-odni-election-security-statement) (released October 7, 2016) from the US Department of Homeland Security (DHS) and the Office of the Director of National Intelligence (ODNI) about recent leaked emails.

> The U.S. Intelligence Community (USIC) is confident that the Russian Government directed the recent compromises of e-mails from US persons and institutions, including from US political organizations. [...] We believe, based on the scope and sensitivity of these efforts, that **only Russia's senior-most officials could have authorized these activities**.

Is there confirmation of the highest levels of Russian government's role behind this, beyond taking the DHS and ODNI's word for it?

Comment: you mean the DNCs and Hillary campaign's word? The claim that wikileaks is part of Russian intelligence comes from there...

Comment: @jwenting: Please see the linked joint statement, which comes from the DHS and ODNI, not from the DNC or Hillary's campaign. The question does not ask if "wikileaks is part of Russian intelligence".

Comment: @Oddthinking - the cynic in me begs to remember that DHS and [ODNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_R._Clapper) are led by politicians appointed by, and reporting to, the President who is DNC's and Hillary's champion (or at least partisan). Given the recent leaks that agents in DOJ and FBI strongly disagreed with handling of investigation into Hillary's emails, that line of thinking is at the very least a requirement for anyone who doesn't automatically believe in argument from authority.

Comment: This speculation, true or false, is a distraction from the question, which asks if a particular statement is true, not what the motivation is.